# Unable to wrap Text inside Container in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following tree: `Scaffold > Column > Row > Container > Text`.
I want the Text to wrap, and The Great Google in most cases told me that Expanded is what i need, but none of the below cases worked for me:

- Row wrapped inside Expanded
- Container wrapped inside Expanded
- Text wrapped inside Expanded

All of the above have the same [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IobPy.png).

Here's my code for the page's body:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF282B32),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          createRow(
            context,
            "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Utrc.jpg?s=256&g=1",
            "GuildProtect is a powerful, baterries-included moderation bot for your *safe* server!"
          ),
          createDivider(),
          createRow(
            context, 
            "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/967406876029501462/bd3c60dcf55c83fba41b15fba89f798a.webp?size=256", 
            "This is a very beatiful (because it's pink) avatar of this shitty website creator, enjoy!"
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }

  Row createRow(BuildContext context, String imageUrl, String text) {
    const containerHeight = 256.0;

    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          height: containerHeight,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, top: 25, bottom: 25),
          child: Image.network(imageUrl),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          height: containerHeight,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, top: 25),
          child: Text(
            text,
            style: TextStyle(
              color: const Color(0xFFFFFCF9),
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.3).fontSize,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ]
    );
  }

  Divider createDivider() {
    return const Divider(
      color: Color(0xFF131518),
      indent: 30,
      endIndent: 30,
      thickness: 1,
      height: 20,
    );
  }
}
```

I also saw some answers on SO recommending to cut the text or show ellipsis, but i dont need this behaviour, i need the text to actually wrap. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3VvxU4EL51M) video's second solution shows exactly what i want to achieve (and no, the solution from there didn't help).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In createRow(), wrap the **second** Container() with Flexible().

```
Flexible(
  child: Container(
    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
    height: containerHeight,
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, top: 25),
    child: Text(
      text,
      style: TextStyle(
        color: const Color(0xFFFFFCF9),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: DefaultTextStyle.of(context)
            .style
            .apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.3)
            .fontSize,
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Lemme know if it worked for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Anywhere you want to use a text and its length is not specified, you may encounter a folding error.
My suggestion is to use [Expanded](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).

**This is the output of your code snippet in my simulator**
[your code Output in mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UvpA.png)

[image]
*It is enough to wrap the second Container with an Expanded widget* (createRow) :

```
Row createRow(BuildContext context, String imageUrl, String text) {
const containerHeight = 256.0;

return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      height: containerHeight,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, top: 25, bottom: 25),
      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
    ),
   --> Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        height: containerHeight,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, top: 25),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xFFFFFCF9),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style.apply(fontSizeFactor: 1.3).fontSize,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]
);
}
```

and output:

--> [after Wrap Container with Expanded Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQILg.png)

It is noteworthy that this part of your work is not responsive.
Probably, the texts are too big in my emulator because of the difference made by the DefaultTextStyle.of(context) class.
Anyway, I hope it solved your problem.

---

*full code:*

I used MediaQuery for setting fontSize Because no details are provided from the content of the defaultTextStyle class.

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TstPage extends StatelessWidget {
const TstPage({super.key});

@override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF282B32),
  body: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      createRow(
        context,
        "https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Utrc.jpg?s=256&g=1",
        "GuildProtect is a powerful, baterries-included moderation bot for 
   your *safe* server!"
      ),
      createDivider(),
      createRow(
        context,     


"https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/967406876029501462/bd3c60dcf55c83fba41b15fba89f798a.webp?size=256", 
            "This is a very beatiful (because it's pink) avatar of this shitty 
 website creator, enjoy!"
      )
    ]
  )
);
}

Row createRow(BuildContext context, String imageUrl, String text) {
const containerHeight = 256.0;

return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
      height: containerHeight,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 50, top: 25, bottom: 25),
      child: Image.network(imageUrl),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        height: containerHeight,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 50, top: 25),
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: const Color(0xFFFFFCF9),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ]
);
}

  Divider createDivider() {
   return const Divider(
   color: Color(0xFF131518),
  indent: 30,
  endIndent: 30,
  thickness: 1,
  height: 20,
);
}
  }
```

[image]

Comment: In the original post i have already mentioned that this solution didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you seeing this?.

Well, this is because the width of the widgets which you are trying to put, is greater then the screen size.

Possible solutions:

- Try to add `width` property to the second `Container` in the `Row`
- try to use `.fit` property, which will fit the image in it's father widget size.
- I don't think that wrapping the `container` in `Expanded` wouldn't fix the situation as I see the text is too long (the screen has overflowed by 260 pixels).
- Try to use `TextOverflow` as mentioned in [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow.html).

Please, let me know if any of my solutions works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).